# hawtio integration with SpringBoot shows login page

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, hawtio

hawtio integration with SpringBoot and Apache Camel shows login page and invalid credentials for admin/admin.

Here is the code snippet :

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.hawt</groupId>
            <artifactId>hawtio-springboot</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-management</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

**application.properties**

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.includes=hawtio,jolokia

spring.jmx.enabled=true

hawtio.authenticationEnabled=false
```

On trying to access

http://localhost:9090/actuator/hawtio

it is getting redirected to

http://localhost:9090/actuator/hawtio/auth/login

and giving invalid credentials for admin/admin

Comment: I can't reproduce starting from https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/tree/main/examples/springboot with your version. You should do the same to spot your problem